How to check type of object property with node's assert?
In jest I might write something like
expect(myObj).toEqual({
  now: expect.any(Date),
  count: expect.any(Number),
  foo: 'bar',
});

How would I write the equivalent using node's test runner?
import assert from 'node:assert';

assert.deepEqual({
  now: ???,
  count: ???,
  foo: 'bar',
});


First of all you forgot myObj :-) But I doubt node's deepEqual has matchers like Jest, so this might simply not be possible.
